# How can I fix this error? ValueError and TypeError. Slider

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, slider, sympy

Issues:

**TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'**

**ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)**

***Line 32 grap_plot, = mplt.plot(x,F,'r')***

**Summary**

I have a sympy fuction ("U"), U depends on x and t, which are Symbolic variables, then I switch from sympy to numpy using lambdify, because I want to plot U using a slider that depends on t, but I can't

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
from sympy.plotting import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
init_printing()
( x, t, n) = symbols('x t n' , positive = True)
Ro= Rational(10,1)**-3 #[Kg/m]
T= Rational(49) #[N]
L = Rational(1) #[m]
c = sqrt(T/Ro)
f = x*(x-1)**2
b = simplify((2/L)*integrate(f*sin(n*pi*x/L),(x,0,L)))
U = expand(summation(b*sin(n*pi*x/L)*cos(c*n*pi*t/L),(n,1,10)))
U0 = simplify(U.subs({t:0}))
mplt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
p = plot(f,(x,0,L))
F = (lambdify(['x','t'], U ,'numpy'))
F0 = (lambdify('x', U0,'numpy'))
x = np.arange(0, L, 0.1)
fig = mplt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
grap_ax = mplt.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.65])
slider_ax = mplt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.05])
mplt.axes(grap_ax) 
mplt.title('Movimiento de la cuerda')
grap_plot, = mplt.plot(x,F,'r')
mplt.xlim(0, L)
mplt.ylim(-0.15, 0.15)
t_slider = Slider(slider_ax,'t',1, 10,0)
def update(t):
    grap_plot.set_ydata(F) 
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()     
t_slider.on_changed(update)
mplt.show()
```

I've tried a lot but I can't fixed it, some help please and thank you.

Comment: Please provide  the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Trace the offending values at the point of failure.

Comment: grap_plot, = mplt.plot(x,F,'r') Line error.

Comment: I have a sympy fuction ("U"), U depends on x and t, which are Symbolic variables, then I switch from sympy to numpy using lambdify, because I want to plot U using a slider that depends on t, but I can't .

Answer (score 0):

The [sympy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) shows that the return of `lambdify` is a function. When you are plotting this against a range matplotlib is therefore getting confused as it expects two equal length array-types. You have to then generate the points using your lambda.

```
plt.plot(x, F(x), 'r', label = 'Fixed function')
```

This will fix both errors - you will pass two equal length arrays and of the same type.

Comment: I have a sympy fuction ("U"), U depends on x and t, which are Symbolic variables, then I switch U from sympy to numpy using lambdify, because I want to plot U using a slider that depends on t, but I can't. U[x,t], x[0,1] and t [0,10]. Actually I did the same with Mathematica Wolfram, but I don't like, that's why I switched to Python.

Comment: I've tried what you said, It didn't work.
`float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function`

Comment: Try using `print(F(x))` to see what type `F(x)` is. It should be an array type, you can check the sympy docs to see how to convert this in to something that matplotlib will be happy plotting against x.

Comment: I solved that error, now I can't make the slider work ... 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Slider'

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, you would do well to read a little more about how python works as a language. Currently, it looks like you are using it as a tool without understanding the syntax; this will only get you so far. If you have the time to invest in a book or watching some free online videos and courses, your understanding of the language will come on leaps and bounds and thus the number of tasks you will find it useful for and the things you can do will increase as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the 2 errors, but I have another one, when I run the code everything is fine but when I use the slider, I got a Type error.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
from sympy.plotting import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
init_printing()
( x, t, n) = symbols('x t n' , positive = True)
Ro= Rational(10,1)**-3 #[Kg/m]
T= Rational(49) #[N]
L = Rational(1) #[m]
c = sqrt(T/Ro)
f = x*(x-1)**2
b = simplify((2/L)*integrate(f*sin(n*pi*x/L),(x,0,L)))
U = expand(summation(b*sin(n*pi*x/L)*cos(c*n*pi*t/L),(n,1,10)))
u = b*sin(n*pi*x/L)*cos(c*n*pi*t/L)
freq = nfloat(n*c/(2*L),6)
Peri = nfloat(1/freq,3)
for i in range (1,4):
    init_printing()
    display(u.subs({n:i}))
    display(freq.subs({n:i}))
    display(Peri.subs({n:i}))
mplt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
p = plot(f,(x,0,L))
F = lambdify(['x','t'], U ,'numpy')
x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
t_init = 0.
fig = mplt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
grap_ax = mplt.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.65])
slider_ax = mplt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.05])
mplt.axes(grap_ax) 
mplt.title('Movimiento de la cuerda')
grap_plot, = mplt.plot(x,F(x,t_init),'r')
mplt.xlim(0, 1)
mplt.ylim(-0.15, 0.15)
t_slider = Slider(slider_ax,'t',0., 10., valinit=t_init)
def update(t):
    grap_plot.set_ydata(F(x,t_slider)) 
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()     
t_slider.on_changed(update)
mplt.show()
```

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Slider'***

Answer (score 0):

**Everything is Fine Thank you**

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
from sympy.plotting import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
init_printing()
( x, t, n) = symbols('x t n' , positive = True)
Ro= Rational(10,1)**-3 #[Kg/m]
T= Rational(49) #[N]
L = Rational(1) #[m]
c = sqrt(T/Ro)
f = x*(x-1)**2
b = simplify((2/L)*integrate(f*sin(n*pi*x/L),(x,0,L)))
U = expand(summation(b*sin(n*pi*x/L)*cos(c*n*pi*t/L),(n,1,10)))
u = b*sin(n*pi*x/L)*cos(c*n*pi*t/L)
freq = nfloat(n*c/(2*L),6)
Peri = nfloat(1/freq,3)
for i in range (1,4):
    init_printing()
    display(u.subs({n:i}))
    display(freq.subs({n:i}))
    display(Peri.subs({n:i}))
mplt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
p = plot(f,(x,0,L))

F = lambdify(['x','t'], U ,'numpy')
x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
t_init = 0
fig = mplt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
grap_ax = mplt.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.65])
slider_ax = mplt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.05])
mplt.axes(grap_ax) 
mplt.title('Movimiento de la cuerda')
grap_plot, = mplt.plot(x,F(x,t_init),'r')
mplt.xlim(0, 1)
mplt.ylim(-0.15, 0.15)
t_slider = Slider(slider_ax,'t',0, 10, valinit=t_init,valfmt="%i")
def update(t):
    grap_plot.set_ydata(F(x,t)) 
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()     
t_slider.on_changed(update)
mplt.show()
```